# Executing a conditional merge

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, conditional-operator

I have a 2 data frames which are :

```
df1                                              
Column1        Column2        
A               id1             
B               id2             
C               id3             
B               id2             
D               id4             
A               id1             
C               id3

df2
Column1      Column2      Column3
X             m1            m2
A             m3            m4
A             m3            m4
Y             n1            n2
A             m3            m4
Z             p1            p2
X             m1            m2
```

I want to merge `df1` and `df2` based on the condition that if the row in column 1 of `df1` is `A`, it should selectively merge columns 2 and 3 from `df2` based on column 2 of `df1`

so the final df1 would look like this:

```
df1                                                                           

Column1        Column2.1    Column1.2      Column2.2      Column3.2
A               id1             id1             m3            m4
B               id2                                   
C               id3         
B               id2         
D               id4         
A               id1             id1             m3            m4
C               id3
```

So far I have managed this by specifically extracting rows which contain "A" in column 1 of df1. then I had applied a merge inside a for loop to get both columns of `df2`. Is there a possibility of having an if loop that helps to specifically perform the conditional merge between `df1` and `df2` ?

Here's the structure of `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Column2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Column1", "Column2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))


df2 <- structure(list(Column1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), Column2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("m1", "m3", "n1", "p1"), class = "factor"), 
    Column3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("m2", 
    "m4", "n2", "p2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Column1", 
"Column2", "Column3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: It might be more helpful if you provided us with an actual sample from your two input columns, the code you have used to do the job so far, and your expected output. You can indent all of this so that it is properly formatted by using the `{}` button on highlighted text.

Comment: @jilber, you're too kind to do all of this work on behalf of the original poster.

Comment: thank you @AnandaMahto, I just wanted to improve a little the question.

Comment: Is the third column Column1.2 redundant as  Column2.1.   I have managed to get rest columns in required manneer except Column1.2

Comment: I will vote for a reproducible example and the desired result. What we have now is just a little below the line (for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if df1 and df2 are defined as above mentioned

```
library(sqldf)


final<-sqldf("select df1.Column1 as Column1 ,df1.Column2,(Select distinct df2.Column2 from df2 where df2.Column1=df1.Column1) as Column2_2,(Select distinct df2.Column3 from df2 where df2.Column1=df1.Column1)as Column3_2 from df1 left join df2 on df1.Column1=df2.Column2")


Column1.2<-ifelse(final$Column1=="A",final$Column2,NA)


final<-cbind(final,Column1.2)
```